# Appending element at specific position in nested list

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have created a nested list l=[[-1]]*5
Now i want to append at position 2.
How can I?

what happens

```
l = [[-1]]*5
>>> l
[[-1], [-1], [-1], [-1], [-1]]
>>> l[2].append(4)
>>> l
[[-1, 4], [-1, 4], [-1, 4], [-1, 4], [-1, 4]]
```

what I want is to append only at index2

```
>>> l
[[-1], [-1], [-1, 4], [-1], [-1]]
```

Comment: `[[-1]]*5` gives you 5 references to the same inner list.  To get 5 *different* inner lists, you can do `[[-1] for i in range(5)]`.  This will create a new inner list for each outer list position.

Comment: `l = [[-1]]*5; index = 2; l[index] = l[index] + [-4]; print(l)`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in a nessted list you can only realy call a section of the outer list and cant the inner if you extact the inner and add it then you can:
x = []
For i in 1:
    x = x + 1[n]
    N = n + 1

Comment: The other guy said that as well...